# How to express these model relationships

Tags: sql, laravel, relational-database, laravel-4, entity-relationship

I'm not sure about the best way to express a relationship between models in my Laravel 4 application. I have three models that I am using to store information in a database: `Employer`, `Employee` and `User`. Basically, the `Employer` and `Employee` models are just going to contain meta information about the `User` model. I think the following expression is the best I can think of:

- `Employer` has many `Employee`
- `Employee` belongs to one `Employer`
- `Employer` belongs to one `User`
- `Employee` belongs to one `User`

In the database, I am going to have a `user_id` foreign key in both the `employers` and `employees` tables that reference the `id` field in the `users` table. Is this the best way to model this domain?

Comment: To be clear, a User can be an employer OR an employee, correct? If so, you may want a [polymorphic relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations)

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Can an employee have more than one employer? Can an employee be employed at more than one place? Do you want to delete records if an employee leaves (and lose history)?

If you can delete the employee record when the employee leaves you can just have an employer_id field in the employee table. But just be prepared that you won't be able to easily add capabilities if you need them in the future.

If you want to prepare for the future: You might want to have a table that says

```
employer_id
employee_id
start_date
end_date
```

And even then if an employee comes and then leaves you have records with the same employer_id, employee_id. So that makes it look like you need an internal key and have say:

```
employment_record_id // this is the primary key
employer_id
employee_id
start_date
end_date
```

I'm not sure exactly what users are but ask yourself the same types of questions:

1. Can a user exist with an employee record
2. Can you have employees without a user record
3. Can a employees user record change
4. Can a users employee record change

Comment: No,an employee can only have one employer. Also, no record will be retained if an employee leaves.